# Каким образом вытащить только второй тег <p> в каждом дочернем элементе?

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Нужно вытащить второй тег "p" в котором пишется время. В дочернем элементе 2 таких тэга. Первый описывает жанры фильма, второй соответсвенно время. Каким образом это сделать?

Мой код:

```
   def ParsePage(host, url):
        html = urlopen(url)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
        for item in bsObj.findAll("div", class_="session clear"):
            children = item.findChildren(recursive=True)
            for child in children:
            if(child.name=="p" and 'class' not in child.attrs):
                time_duration = child.text
                if(time_duration==''):
                    time_duration = 'Неизвестно'
                    print(time_duration)
                else:
                print(time_duration)

ParsePage("https://cinemaciti.ua/", "https://cinemaciti.ua/fontan-sky-center/rozklad")
```

Работает так:

```
детектив, трилер, жахи 
95 хв.
бойовик, драма, трилер 
114 хв.
мультфільм 
87 хв.
фентезі 
94 хв.
містика, жахи 
118 хв.
документальний 
98 хв.
драма, кримінал, трилер 
153 хв.
пригоди, фантастика 
102 хв.
комедія 
95 хв.
бойовик, драма, кримінал, фантастика 
102 хв.
комедія, мультфільм 
99 хв.
Неизвестно
136 хв.
пригоди, сімейний 
118 хв.
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробывать так:

```
children = item.findChild(recursive=True).findNext("p")
```

Есть функция в bs4 `findNext()` она возвращает вам следующий элемент.

[Github](https://tedboy.github.io/bs4_doc/generated/generated/bs4.BeautifulSoup.findNext.html)